# How do I add the details of the user who compiled project to AssemblyDescription attribute in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

The problem isn't much more than the title I'm afraid.

I have a Visual Studio 2010 solution that many people work on and and deploy and I need to add the details of the person who compiled that particular version of the assembly to the AssemblyInfo.cs file, more specifically the AssemblyDescription attribute.

Any ideas as how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Add a Pre-build event which rewrites the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file.**

You could even add a second file named `PersonDetails.cs` which you don't put in source control (i.e. into the ignore list) in which you only put the persons details.

The build event would be a small application you write which gets the user name from e.g. the Windows credentials and puts it in the C# file.